# Windows IoT Core flashing unsuccessful unless Windows Defender 'Real-time protection' is disabled

Tags: windows-iot-core-10

Unless I disable Windows Defender 'Real-time protection', I get a 'Flashing Unsuccessful' error message while trying to setup a new Raspberry Pi device using Windows IoT Core Dashboard.

[image]

This is how my advanced settings are configured.

[image]

The OS on the machine on which I am having this problem is `Microsoft Windows 10 Pro - 10.0.17134 Build 17134`.

And this is the card reader that I am using. It is the standard one that comes built in to the Dell XPS tower (not an external USB reader for example).

[image]

I have tried setting up exclusions etc. but have not so far found one that will work.

[image]

What exclusions should I create so that I can leave 'Real-time' protection running?

Comment: What are the settings of IoT Dashboard->Settings->Advanced ?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have everything checked. I have now added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Hi Scott, can you reproduce this issue on another PC? Do you mind showing your OS information? Under System Information->OS Name and Version.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I will try reproducing this on another machine when I get a chance. In the meantime, the one on which I have been having the problem is - Microsoft Windows 10 Pro - 10.0.17134 Build 17134.

Comment: Hi Scott, some USB Flash drives treat SDCards as hard drives – which might trigger the realtime protection. Could you show a screenshot of the Card reader in device manager?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I added a screenshot of my card reader in device manager. I hope that is what you were after?

Comment: Hi Scott, Is there any other processes on the PC that might try to access the SD card when it’s plugged in, like auto-importing which might also trigger the real-time protection?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. How could I check that?